# Knowing keys type of array?

Tags: php, arrays

is there a command to know if an array has their keys as string or plain int?

Like:

```
$array1 = array('value1','value2','value3');
checkArr($array1); //> Returns true because there aren't keys as string
```

And:

```
$array2 = array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2','value3');
checkArr($array2); //> Returns false because there are keys as string
```

Note: I know I can parse all the array to check it.

Comment: Does it have to check for 0-based sequential index, or will 'any' int do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "compact" version to test this is:

```
$allnumeric =
array_sum(array_map("is_numeric", array_keys($array))) == count($array);
```

@Gumbo's suggestion is 1 letter shorter and could very well be a bit speedier for huge arrays:

```
count(array_filter(array_keys($array), "is_numeric")) == count($array);
```

Comment: Better use `array_filter` instead of `array_map` and `array_sum`.

Comment: Good idea. One could exchange the array_sum() for another count() then probably.

Comment: @yes123: See edit. The params are just ordered a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys](http://www.php.net/array_keys) to obtain the keys for the array and then analyse the resultant array.

Answer (score 0):

look at [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) if values are int - you got ints if strings -> strings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *check* the array's keys, it would be probably better to use something like this:

```
reset($array);
while (($key = key($array)) !== null) {
    // check the key, for example:
    if (is_string($key)) {
        // ...
    }
    next($array);
}
```

This will be most performant, as there are no extraneous copies made of variables that you are not going to use.

On the other hand, this way is probably the most readable and makes the intent crystal clear:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    // check the key, for example:
    if (is_string($key)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Take your pick.

**Important note:**

Last time I checked, **PHP would not let you have keys which are string representations of integers**. For example:

```
$array = array();
$array["5"] = "foo";

echo $array[5]; // You might think this will not work, but it will
```

So keep that in mind when you are checking what the types of such keys are: they might have been *created* as strings, but PHP will have converted them to integers behind the scenes.